# C# first http request (HttpClient/WebClient/WebRequest) taking a long time (60+ Seconds) on some sites?

Tags: c#, .net, https, httpclient, webclient

I'm trying to load various sites to get some information in C# but there are a quite a few sites (not all) where the first request is taking 30-60 seconds.

As an example;

```cs
var url = "https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/cases/mid-tower/masterbox-k501l";
using var wc = new WebClient();
Console.WriteLine(wc.DownloadString(url));
```

This will consistently take 30-60 seconds every time I first run the app, fiddler says the connection stays in "CONNECT" state but then eventually returns the page content.

I've tried using `HttpClient` (and disabling proxy via `HttpClientHandler`), using `HttpClientFactory`, using `WebRequest.Create` but no luck.

If I use any command line tools (cURL, wget) it returns instantly, also works instantly doing requests from other languages (JS/Ruby/PHP/Python), but no luck in .NET, even if I send the exact same headers as the other tools send. Tried on various computers, different internet connections, vps, etc.

None of these sites block bots, it's explicitly allowed in `robots.txt`.

Am I hitting some kind of bug, or is there any option I'm missing? It seems to be related to a slow SSL handshake but I'm not sure?

Comment: @Heagon thanks, but that link doesn't answer my question. It's not just WebClient being slow, it's every method I've tried in .NET (WebClient/HttpClient/WebRequest), and it's only on some sites.

Comment: I'd suspect resolving dns is the problem. I'd assume that your machine has multiple dns servers, the first of which isn't working.

Comment: Could also be due to an IPv6 request timing out.